# Detecting a hot reload in React Native

Tags: react-native, reselect

Is there a variable that exposes the ID / count of the current hot reload in React Native, or alternatively any other way of detecting a hot reload?

For context, I have a dynamic `require` behind a reselect selector which doesn't get invalidated when one of the required files changes. I can work around the problem by using a less efficient implementation when `__DEV__` is true, but I'd prefer something that I can add as a selector dependency.

Comment: i don't think right now there is any way. you can open an issue here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues

Answer (score 4):

On iOS, I was able to use the `RCTBridgeWillReloadNotification` event:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
  self,
  selector: #selector(self.test),
  name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "RCTBridgeWillReloadNotification"),
  object: nil)
```